# Anti-Zionism in Bentching?

Tags: history, prayer-book, bentching, zionism

Recently at a Shabbos table I heard that the addition to shir hama'alot "Tehillat Hashem" (a compilation of four verses beginning with Psalms 145:21) was anti-zionistic and shouldn't be said. I heard alternatively that these additions dated to at least as far back as the time of the Arizal. Can anyone explain how these tehillim could be anti-Zionistic, or provide any historical sources for their coming before Zionism?

Comment: Well, the Yeckes (German Jews) traditionally say them, and they are also traditionally anti-Zionist. But I don't think the verses themselves have any such connotation. Also, if a religious Zionist finds that verses of Tanach are anti-Zionist, I would assume that he would abandon his Zionism rather than abandon the verses. Except of course if his belief in Zionism is stronger than his belief in Tanach...

Comment: @Adám My question is what is the history of the addition to these phrases to Bentching

Comment: @Adám To use an extreme and very awful example, nobody wants to say Devarim 14:53 before bentching, but that doesn't mean we're abandoning it.  If it was Bamidbar 14:41-43 I could understand the question.  But I have no idea what תהלת ה' has to do with anything other than praising Hashem.

Comment: It seems very strange, the verses are apparently not linked with Zionism.

Comment: `was anti-zionistic and shouldn't be said` These seem like two different points, being conflated.